# How to reload tile which is not loaded in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am searching for solution, how to reload tile in leaflet.js which is not loaded due error 503. 
Thank you

Comment: Searching for `leaflet reload tiles` gave me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048096/how-do-i-force-a-leaflet-map-to-reload-all-tiles-including-visible-ones

Comment: I saw this answer, but I dobt want reload all tiles, just the one which is not loaded due error 503

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API I put this code together which should help you solve the problem:

```
 function reloadImg() { // reload image by changing its src
  var src = $(this).attr("src");
  var i = src.lastIndexOf('?');
  if(i > 0) { // remove previous cache string
   src = src.substring(0, i);
  }
  $(this).attr("src", src + "?nocache=" + (Math.random() * 1000));
 }

 map.on('layeradd', function(ILayer) { // on adding a new tile
    if($.isFunction(ILayer.layer.getContainer)) { // get the container holding the images
     $("img", ILayer.layer.getContainer()).error(reloadImg); // apply error handling event
    }
 });
```