# Dynamically reload leaflet tiles

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I would like to load specific leaflet tiles, based on changes to the user's activity. So, say, a user opens the map and sees particular tiles. Then, after a few minutes, some tiles are reloaded (because they have changed) and displayed. Perhaps the original was orange, the new one is blue.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048096/how-do-i-force-a-leaflet-map-to-reload-all-tiles-including-visible-ones) give a suggestion that could work for refreshing *all* the tiles, but that would be rather inefficient.

Is there a way to force the reload of specific individual tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm way to late, but I have a solution to this. You can manipulate the url using a parameter that you update only for the tiles that should reload. The rest will keep the cached tile image.

```
L.TileLayer.CustomLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: (coords) => {
        var test = some_function_deciding_test_based_on_tile(coords);
        return `http://example.com/tile_${coords.x}_${coords.y}.png?test=${test}`;
    }
});
```

In this case if `some_function_deciding_test_based_on_tile(coords)` returns the same value as it did the previous time, the cached tile will be used. Otherwise a new tile will be fetched.

Comment: Clever and simple.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to implement a plugin for that, subclassing `L.TileLayer` and overwriting its `createTile()` method, so that you either have references to the tiles, or adding some kind of timeout or logic to each (loading/loaded) tile.

There's no *generic* way of doing this as of now, you'll have to code it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this.